# DataList Using ajax call(Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms, datalist

I don't know why this is happening at all. As the same code is working for GridView Control but not working for DataList control. The code given below is for asp.net Web Page having DataList control loaded using ajax call(Data Binding is done using ajax).

Following error occurs: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.

The error occurs at the time of page load.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ADataList.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebServices.controls.ADataList" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Customer ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Country</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="CustomerId" style="margin-left: 160px">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerId") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td id="Name">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" Style="display: none" />
                        </td>
                        <td id="Country">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>' runat="server" Style="display: none" />

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:LinkButton Text="Edit" runat="server" CssClass="Edit" />
                            <asp:LinkButton Text="Update" runat="server" CssClass="Update" Style="display: none" />
                            <asp:LinkButton Text="Cancel" runat="server" CssClass="Cancel" Style="display: none" />
                            <asp:LinkButton Text="Delete" runat="server" CssClass="Delete" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
            <table style="border-collapse: collapse">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 150px">Name:<br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="140" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 150px">Country:<br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Width="140" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 100px">
                        <br />
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "service.asmx/GetCustomers",
                data: '{}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess
            });
        });

        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var customers = xml.find("Table");
            var row = $("[id*=DataList1] tr:last-child");
            if (customers.length > 0) {
                $.each(customers, function () {
                    AppendRow(row, $(this).find("CustomerId").text(), $(this).find("Name").text(), $(this).find("Country").text()),
                        row = $("[id*=DataList1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                });
            } else {
                row.find(".Edit").hide();
                row.find(".Delete").hide();
                row.find("span").html('&nbsp;');
            }
        }

        function AppendRow(row, customerId, name, country) {
            //Bind CustomerId.
            $("#CustomerId", row).find("span").html(customerId);

            //Bind Name.
            $("#Name", row).find("span").html(name);
            $("#Name", row).find("input").val(name);

            //Bind Country.
            $("#Country", row).find("span").html(country);
            $("#Country", row).find("input").val(country);

            row.find(".Edit").show();
            row.find(".Delete").show();
            $("[id*=DataList1]").append(row); //This line is giving error on running .each
        }

        //Add event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "[id*=btnAdd]", function () {
            var txtName = $("[id*=txtName]");
            var txtCountry = $("[id*=txtCountry]");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "service.asmx/InsertCustomer",
                data: '{name: "' + txtName.val() + '", country: "' + txtCountry.val() + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var row = $("[id*=DataList1] tr:last-child");
                    if ($("[id*=DataList1] tr:last-child span").eq(0).html() !== "&nbsp;") {
                        row = row.clone();
                    }
                    AppendRow(row, response.d, txtName.val(), txtCountry.val());
                    txtName.val("");
                    txtCountry.val("");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

        //Edit event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "[id*=DataList1] .Edit", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                    $(this).find("input").show();
                    $(this).find("span").hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Update").show();
            row.find(".Cancel").show();
            row.find(".Delete").hide();
            $(this).hide();
            return false;
        });

        //Update event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "[id*=DataList1] .Update", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                    var span = $(this).find("span");
                    var input = $(this).find("input");
                    span.html(input.val());
                    span.show();
                    input.hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Edit").show();
            row.find(".Delete").show();
            row.find(".Cancel").hide();
            $(this).hide();

            var customerId = row.find("#CustomerId").find("span").html();
            var name = row.find("#Name").find("span").html();
            var country = row.find("#Country").find("span").html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "service.asmx/UpdateCustomer",
                data: '{customerId: ' + customerId + ', name: "' + name + '", country: "' + country + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });

            return false;
        });

        //Cancel event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "[id*=DataList1] .Cancel", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            $("td", row).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("input").length > 0) {
                    var span = $(this).find("span");
                    var input = $(this).find("input");
                    input.val(span.html());
                    span.show();
                    input.hide();
                }
            });
            row.find(".Edit").show();
            row.find(".Delete").show();
            row.find(".Update").hide();
            $(this).hide();
            return false;
        });

        //Delete event handler.
        $("body").on("click", "[id*=DataList1] .Delete", function () {
            if (confirm("Do you want to delete this row?")) {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                var customerId = row.find("span").html();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "service.asmx/DeleteCustomer",
                    data: '{customerId: ' + customerId + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        if ($("[id*=DataList1] tr").length > 2) {
                            row.remove();
                        } else {
                            row.find(".Edit").hide();
                            row.find(".Delete").hide();
                            row.find("span").html('&nbsp;');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Click here to see the output: In this image only the first record is showing on output from the database. This means the .each loop is running only once and giving error on this line $("[id*=DataList1]").append(row);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpgfQ.png)

Comment: Please specific when does the error comes, when you click add or ?

Comment: At the time of page load @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Comment: I think you're not creating a new row. You get the last row at `var row =...` then later, on the line that gives the error, you try to append it, but of course it's already there, so the error is `The new child element contains the parent`.